# How to call the get function from angular service to a component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been learning to create on a coin counter, where I have created a service for coin counter and two components, one component to trigger the counter and another to display the counter value.

I tried the below code.

**coin.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class CoinService {
  
  public coin = 0;

  setCount() {
    this.coin = this.coin + 10;
  }

  getCount(): number {
    return this.coin;
  }

  decrementCount() {
    this.coin = this.coin - 10;
  }
}
```

**one.component.ts**

```
  coin: number = 0;

  constructor(private coinservice: CoinService) {}

  addTask() {
    if (this.onAddItem) {
      this.coinservice.setCount();
      console.log('coin:', this.coinservice.getCount());
    }
  }
```

In the above code, the addTask() is triggerd by a button click. and when I tried logging the result(this.coinservice.getCount()), it provides the right result. But when I tried to call the function coinservice.getCount() in another component, it doesnt work.

**two.component.ts**

```
public coom : number =1;
constructor(private coinservice: CoinService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.coom = this.coinservice.getCount();
}
```

**two.component.html**

```
<img class="coinCount" src="assets/images/coin.png" width="10px" height="10px"> {{coom}}
```

In the above component code, I tried to call the function from the service to display the result of the count triggered by **one.component.ts**. But the result I get is '0'. I would like to receive the count value in the **two.component.ts**. Can someone help me understand how I can do this? I am relatively new to angular. So any help would be appreciated!.

Comment: Are you aware that you're only setting `this.coom` once when the component is created? I think you need a "refresh" of some sorts in your `two.component.ts` to get the current coin value.

Comment: @MikeS. could you show how to do that?

Comment: It's hard to say if that really is the problem because you didn't provide any reproducible example, but you basically need to execute `this.coom = this.coinservice.getCount();` when you want `this.zoom` to show the current value of your service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public coin = 0;` should be replaced with `public coin = new Subject();`

and you can `subscribe` to the value everywhere you want to listen to his changes.

```
coinService.coin.subscribe(val => {
  // do what you need with the value
})
```

when you need to update the value simply - `coin.next(10)`